# display radiobuttonlist value without autopostback

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist, autopostback

Current code I have is this RadioButtonList:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged" RepeatColumns="3" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" style="text-align: center" Width="429px">
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="true" Value="6" Text=""></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text=""></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text=""></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

This Label:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

And this code behind:

```
protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue == "6")
            {
                Label1.Text = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue;
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = "no";
            }
        }
```

This is working however this makes the page refresh every time a radio box is changed which is not practical for the situation I'm trying to use this in.  I would like to update the label without post back, is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is how the ASP.NET works ;)

There are some options how to achieve what you want. Choose the one which suits you:

1. utilize [onchange](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) JavaScript event to update the label (you can either use static text or retrieve dynamic content from web server via ajax)
2. wrap the elements you want to update to [`<asp:UpdatePanel...>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel(v=vs.110).aspx) to avoid whole page being refreshed (this solution is in fact ajax made easy by ASP.NET)
3. turn off autopostback (`AutoPostBack="false"`) and update the text when submitting the whole form